# LazyLoader GetView index issue

Tags: listview

I am creating custom list view , where I am using lazy adapter. But I am not able to get current index (position) value at the time of scrolling.When I scroll down it will work like 0,1,2.. but when I scroll half and again come to last image so it is still showing current index 1 (should be 0) . I have to get data according to position values but not able to do this. is there any other way to do these thing?
thanks.